# what is the difference between employ and employment

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I can not understand the difference when *employ* is a noun.

So somebody help me to show the difference between *employ* and *employment*.

Comment: The use of *employ* in the sense of *employment* (in certain contexts) is essentially idiomatic-literary. It is used in set phrases, idiomatic expressions and for 'effect' to sound officious. It is also popular in news reporting.

Comment: @Kris Thank you, and `Employ is just an archaic form of employment` is still true?

Comment: Please see my comment at Noah's answer. It's archaic only in a certain sense. It's is still used in legalese, press reports, literary works, ...

Comment: ... **A few minutes back**, *Business Day* reported: *The fact is, GI — as the good folk on Twitterville like to call Igesund — has managed to infuriate the kind of people no coach **in the employ of** the South African Football Association (Safa) should ever think about rubbing up the wrong way.* http://www.bdlive.co.za/sport/soccer/2014/02/12/negative-publicity-means-igesund-unlikely-to-walk-the-plank

Comment: I think @Noah need to update his answer :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no difference between the two. *Employ* is just an archaic form of *employment.* That said, the verb form of *employ* is the same as the archaic form, so to avoid confusion, it's better to use *employ* as a verb and *employment* as a noun.

Comment: I think it is archaic only in one sense and not generally as a noun. Please check again.

Comment: @Kris: That's true. But the OP is not asking for that. If need be I can include that.

Comment: However, that's what you have stated as part of the answer, right?

Answer (score 1):

**Employ** is a verb.
**Employment** is a noun.

For example

> I would like to **employ** *(verb)* John.
>   John was desperately looking for new **employment** *(noun)* after having been laid off.

You *can* use **employ** as a noun, such as in this example: *"John found himself in his brother's employ."* However, that type of use is archaic and quite uncommon; I would recommend against using it as a noun so as to avoid confusing people.

Comment: The usage of employ as a noun is correct usage, but a bit archaic. It sounds bit *high falootin'* . . . :P

Comment: Also, "employ" can often mean "use", while "employment" almost never does.

Comment: @IQAndreas I think my question is clear, i mean employ is noun when compare. Thank for your answer :-)

Comment: When you are 'not sure' of the usage, how would you make a categorical statement at the opening of the answer that "*Employ* is a verb"? http://www.thefreedictionary.com/employ

Comment: @Kris What I meant was, I know some people use **employ** as a noun _in practice_. What I didn't know was whether their usage of the word is _incorrect grammar_ or not. (but thanks for the link, I adjusted the wording of the answer accordingly)

Comment: It's not even archaic as such.